# Unit Test - How to set controller user to Generic Principal object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, tdd, asp.net-apicontroller

Updated full solution:

WebApi Controller method which I'm going to test :

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using System.Web.Http;


[Authorize]
public class GigsController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public GigsController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }        

    [HttpDelete]
    public IHttpActionResult Cancel(int id)
    {
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var gig = _unitOfWork.Gigs.GetGigWithAttendees(id);

        if (gig.IsCanceled)
            return NotFound();

        if (gig.ArtistId != userId)
            return Unauthorized();

        gig.Cancel();

        _unitOfWork.Complete();

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Unit Test class :

```
[TestClass]
public class GigsControllerTests
{
    private GigsController _controller;
    public GigsControllerTests()
    {
        var identity = new GenericIdentity("user1@domain.com");
        identity.AddClaim(
            new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name", "user1@domain.com"));
        identity.AddClaim(
            new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", "1"));

        var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, null);

        var mockUoW = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
        _controller = new GigsController(mockUoW.Object);
        _controller.User = principal;
    }
```

I'm getting following error :

> Error CS0200  Property or indexer 'ApiController.User' cannot be
> assigned to -- it is read only

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDQJS.png

Comment: That is incorrect. [`ApiController.User`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.user(v=vs.118).aspx) is not readonly. So you need to provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem. That way we can better assess the true cause of the problem.

Comment: Hi Nkosi, I have updated the full solution, It still showing that the ApiController.User is readonly

Comment: Show `GigsController` declaration as well.

Comment: Just updated mate :)

Comment: I used the code provided to attempt to reproduce your problem but as expected, the code compiles, allowing the value to be assigned to `ApiController.User` property. Unless there is something additional to what you show in your example the error you display is unable to be reproduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this same issue while following Moshi's tutorials, and this stumped me for a good couple of hours before I was finally able to resolve this.

Ultimately, what fixed this for me was changing my using statement from:

*using GigHub.Controllers;*

to

*using GigHub.Controllers.Api;*

Your GigsController _controller is pointing to the Controller itself and not the ApiController. I kinda wish Moshi had put "Api" in the name of his API classes that way you'd know if you were looking at the pure controller or the API version of the controller without having to check namespaces or go to definition on your objects.

You're right that the User property for the Controller class does indeed only have a Get.

```
public abstract class Controller : ControllerBase, IActionFilter, 
IAuthenticationFilter, IAuthorizationFilter, IDisposable, IExceptionFilter, 
IResultFilter, IAsyncController, IController, IAsyncManagerContainer
{
   public IPrincipal User { get; }
}
```

The User property for the ApiController class however has both a Get and Set.

```
public abstract class ApiController : IHttpController, IDisposable
{
    public IPrincipal User { get; set; }
}
```

Hopefully this was your issue as well and helps you out!

Cheers!

Answer (score 11):

You can assign it through `ControllerContext`

```
var user = new ClaimsPrincipal();
var context = new ControllerContext
{
    HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext
    {
        User = user
    }
};

controllerUnderTest.ControllerContext = context;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead set the `CurrentPrincipal` of your executing thread

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
```

Comment: Not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Came across this post when I'm trying to mock a user in a controller, rather than controller.api… and struggled. 
Anyway the way to do it is by overwriting ControllerContext in the controller with a mock object , and the mock object is set up to return the user you wish to mock.

```
var user = CreateLoggedInUser(targetUserID);

mockControllerContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>();

mockControllerContext.Setup(o => o.HttpContext.User).Returns(user);

myCaseController.ControllerContext = mockControllerContext.Object;
```

and

```
private ClaimsPrincipal CreateLoggedInUser(int userID)
    {
        GenericIdentity myIdentity = new GenericIdentity("apiTestUser");
        myIdentity.AddClaims(new List<Claim> {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, userID.ToString()),

        });
        return new ClaimsPrincipal(myIdentity);
    }
```